# Grunt express stays running from watch but not from concurrent

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-express-server

I'm using `grunt-express-server` with `grunt-concurrent` and `grunt-contrib-watch`. I'm also using `load-grunt-config`.

When I run `npm start` my express server starts, logs that it is running, then exits. The watch service stays running, as does grunt. If I make a change to the monitored file, my express server starts and stays running. I've spent several hours reading other answers and blogs and am still not understanding why the initial launch of express exits when grunt is not exiting and what I can do to keep it running.

In my concurrent.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
  return {
    serve: {
        tasks: ['watch:express', 'express:dev' ],
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
    }
  }
};
```

In my express.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
  return {
    options: {
      background: true
    },
    dev: {
      options: {
        script: 'web/server.js'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In my watch.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
  return {
    options: {
      spawn: false,
    },
    express: {
      files: ['web/server.js'],
      tasks: ['express:dev'],
      options: {
        livereload: true
      }
    }
  };
};
```